# jQuery Autocomplete display results containing search keywords

Tags: jquery, search, autocomplete, keyword

I am trying to implement something like google instant seach that displays possible searches as you type in the text box.

So far I got the results as json string and jquery autocomplete display them perfectly. Now I want to show all the results that has search keywords.

**Like say for example, if search keys are "foo bar" and my result has "foo fun bar"; now the "foo" and "bar" keys are contained in the result but current autocomplete plugin doesn't display it.**

Is there a way to modify the plugin to achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need to modify the default behavior of the autocomplete widget's filter function to split the text box value into individual tokens and search the source object on each token.

You can [download the jQuery UI source here](http://jquery-ui.googlecode.com/files/jquery-ui-1.8.15.zip). Have a look at jquery.ui.autocomplete.js line 422 for the filter function you'll need to modify. You'll notice that it returns a test of a regular expression to see if the value object's label member, value member, or the value object itself matches the regular expression. You'd have to instead aggregate the test results on every string in the array returned by a call to [.split()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split) on a string element derived from one of those three sources.

If you'd like to minify your modified autocomplete code, use [Google's Closure Compiler Service](http://closure-compiler.appspot.com/home).

Comment: I modified the jquery.ui.autocomplete.js line 422 (as [lthibodeaux][1] suggested) and it works like charm!Thanks.. For those who are looking for the similar thing to achieve, here is the modified code segment at line 422 in jquery.ui.autocomplete.js
    filter: function(array, term) {
      var matcher;
      var keys = term.split(' '); 
      $.each(keys, function(index, value) {         
       matcher = new RegExp( $.ui.autocomplete.escapeRegex(value), "i" );
      });      
      return $.grep( array, function(value) {
       return matcher.test( value.label || value.value || value ); });}

Answer (score 0):

how do you query your data?  in server site you should get all records ***containing*** your search and not Startwith.

Comment: I do get the results containing the search keywords from server but then I do a formatting on those to form a string like say for example if I look for "seattle 98104" I get "Seattle WA 98104" in result but autocomplete does not display it since the search string does not match because of "WA" token.

Answer (score 0):

Depends on how you get your data. Split the keywords by spaces and list all of the data that has both Foo and Bar.

Comment: Ya I was thinking on the same approach but I was wondering if current autocomplete plugin allow this to do or I will have to modify the code.

Comment: Ah. I hastily read it and thought that you wrote the autocomplete. You'll probably have to do what the other guy mentioned and edit jquery's source